# How to get JSON data within a script using Python

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am trying to obtain JSON data that I see when inspecting the page source for a particular URL. This URL has multiple  tags however only one of these tags has JSON formatted data.

Here is my current implementation:

```
import urllib2 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

url = "https://www.exampleURL.com"

page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')

for script in scripts:
    try:
        data = json.loads(script)
        print("Success")
    except Exception:
        print("Not Successful")
```

This implementation fails to ever print Success. The JSON data I want is in the following format, however there is only one script tag that has JSON data, all others are irrelevant to me.

```
<script>
    __DATA__ = {........};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do some data processing before trying to parse the content of the `<script>` as json. In particular, you'd need to remove the `__DATA__ =` part in front of the JavaScript dictionary.

Few things to keep in mind:

- Javascript dictionaries are not JSON blobs necessarily. In particular

Example

```
{hello: 2}   # Correct JavaScript, incorrect JSON - missing quotes around key
{'hello': 2} # Correct JavaScript, incorrect JSON - Quotes must be double quotes

{"hello": 2} # Correct JSON and JavaScript
```

Few things that might help debugging

```
for script in scripts:
    try:
        print(script) # See what you try to load
        data = json.loads(script)
        print("Success")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Not Successful because {}".format(e)) # Print additional information
```